# Convergence of the series $\sum (a^{1/n}-1)^{\lambda}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a^{1/n}-1)^{\lambda}$$ converges for

$1.\lambda\geq0$

$2.\lambda\geq1$

$3.\lambda>1$

$4.\lambda\leq1$

I am confused about the convergence of the series. No Comarision test is working. Ratio's and rooth test also not working. How to check for convegence. Thanks.

Comment: Summation symbol must always come with the **variable** which you are summing over, otherwise how to know whether it is $n$ or $λ$??

Comment: ok its with $n.$

Comment: Very good! In mathematics it is important to be precise. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the limit $$\lim n(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\ln a$$ to a limit comparison with a harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

By using $e^x=1+x+o(x),$ we have
$$
\frac{a^{1/n}-1}{1/n}\rightarrow\log a
$$
and so (for $a\neq1$) by the comparison test the series converges if and only if $\sum_n1/n^{\lambda}$ converges.